# padding stretching div width HTML5

Tags: css, html

I am trying to keep the width of my div fixed to 200px.
But when I add 20px to the padding, the div is stretched to 240px width.
Is this some quirk of HTML5 or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>My website</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    Hello world
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

It's a box model thing: [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) has some really good CSS3 tricks to change the box model. Essentially, you can change your DIV definition to:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkdLV/)

Answer (score 0):

The box model states that you should reduce the width of your item by the width of any padding and border you add to it.

So in your case make your width 160px and you'll be good.

More info here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Border
 Padding
 Content

width it's a property of content so padding will add px to total width of element